# How to add blank spaces in highcharts subtitle option

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to add blank space in the text below

subtitle: {

```
  text:'<b> WEL#: 0703,Number of Solar Collectors: 2, Slope (from horizontal): 32°, Orientation +32°(west), Auxilary heater: Electric, <br> Location: Westmount Street, Halifax </br> </b>',

},
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a span which matches the color of your background

```
<span style="font-size:16px; color:#ffffff">.</span>
```

It seems high charts removes multiple break tags (ie <BR>) as well as displays &nbsp; as "&nbsp;".

The code above is a "white" period but looks like a space.

Comment: nothing worked except for this, genius!

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending the lines after the break and adding \n to the end of each, like so:

```
{
    subtitle: "The fox went up the hill \n" +
        "and down the other side to \n" +
        "where the chickens lived."
}
```

Also, if you don't see the white space when trying to display it on the page, try wrapping it in `<pre></pre>` to preserve it.

Here's a more in-depth example:
http://www.willmaster.com/blog/javascript/strings-line-breaks.php

Comment: I dont want it to go to the next line. I want everything to be on the same line just want to add two spaces between the words.

Comment: You should just be able to add it in the string.  Is it displaying in a way you aren't expecting?

Comment: Yeah I am not able to see any spaces in between the words.

Comment: That's most likely a CSS issue.  By default the browser tries to collapse unnecessary spaces, tabs and line breaks.  See what happens when you wrap the container with a pre tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can add blank spaces in HTML by using "&nbsp"

Example,

```
   subtitle: {

       text:'<b> WEL#: 0703,Number of Solar Collectors: 2, Slope (from horizontal): 32°, Orientation +32°(west), Auxilary heater: Electric, &nbsp; &nbsp; Location: Westmount Street, Halifax &nbsp; &nbsp; </b>',

  },
```

Comment: It is taking it as a string and not as a space.

Comment: In high charts &nbsp; is not rendered as a space but as a string itself and display the text '&nbsp;'